# Django m2m symmetrical False raises error

Tags: python, django, many-to-many, self

I can't runserver for the model with m2m (ManyToManyField). The models' field itself looks like this:

```
...
class Some(TimeStampedModel):
    relate = models.CharField(max_length=10000, blank=False)
    related_relate = models.ManyToManyField('self', through='RelatedM2M',
            symmetrical=False, related_name=_('related_relate'))
...
```

then facing the import error:

```
django.core.urlresolvers.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'related_phrases' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
```

and I can't understand how it works... From [this](http://www.caktusgroup.com/blog/2009/08/14/creating-recursive-symmetrical-many-to-many-relationships-in-django/) post I've found that I need to `create the reverse relationship manually yourself via the through model` but what does this mean? What exactly happens that it throws this error and how to handle m2m asymmetrical fields in models that are related to themselves?

**Update**
django.core.urlresolvers.NoReverseMatch:

```
class NoReverseMatch(Exception):
    pass
```

??

Comment: reverse relationship of many2many has nothing to do with the URL. do you have any URL with name `related_phrases` ?

Comment: No. only two urls `url(r'^about/$', AboutView.as_view(), name='about'), url(r'^$', 'home', name='home'),` that worked fine before making changes in models. It is exactly the problem in m2m relation because changing the model with `through` raised exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As written [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.related_name) in Django docs, I needed to add `+` in the end of related_name attribute in m2m model and set related_name in m2m field different from its name.